# Accessing data inside std::vector container

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I have three std::vector.

```
typedef std::pair< double,double > A;
typedef std::vector< A > B;
typedef std::vector< B > C;
```

I know how to access the element inside B like

```
B b;
b.at(0).first;
b.at(0).second;
And
C c;
```

How can I access the element of b using the container variable c?
Thanks

Comment: if A and B are variables as well, this isn't valid. Are you missing some `typedef`s in there?

Comment: I made a comment at the same time as WhozCraig, when you posted code that didn't make sense.  I deleted my comment when it was no longer relevant, and might confuse you, which it looks like it did even 10 minutes after being deleted.

Comment: So that makes sense to everyone wondering "huh?" : [prior post before edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21869771/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C.at(0).at(0)` will access first element of `B`. Because `C` is B's container.

Comment: I would recommend `C[0][0]` because `at()` performs additional range checks. It's C++ afterall, you have to have the freedom to shoot-off your leg :)

Comment: Agreed with @user3159253.

Comment: @user3159253 Yes right, but OP has some preferred way, so.

Answer (score 2):

(I know you (or someone) updated the question to fix the lack of `typedef`s - just leaving this as relevant to the original question in case it helps someone else).

You need to understand the difference between a *type* and an object/variable/instance of that type.  For example, `double` is a type, and if you say:

```
double x;
```

Then you've defined a variable `x` of type `double` in which you can store one number.

In a sense, types are saying ***how*** to use some memory to record a value of that type.  Type's aren't told ***where*** the memory they're to manage is - that's only done when you define one or more variables of that type.

The templates `std::pair<>` and `std::vector<>` expect their parameters to be types: for example `std::vector<int>` is an instantiation of the `std::vector` template for the parameter `int`, and is itself a new type which you can use to create a variable:

```
std::vector<int> vi;
```

So, to your code:

```
std::pair< double,double > A;
std::vector< A > B;
std::vector< B > C;
```

The first line creates a variable called `A` of type `std::pair<double,double>`.
The second line tries to instantiate `std::vector<>` with the variable from the last line, which won't work - the `std::vector<>` template must be instantiated with a type.  To make it work, we need:

```
typedef std::pair< double,double > A;
std::vector< A > B;
```

The `typedef` keyword indicates that the first line is creating an alternative name for `std::pair<double, double>`, so the above definition for the variable `B` is entirely equivalent to:

```
std::vector< std::pair<double, double> > B;
```

Then your next line repeats the just-fixed mistake the second line made, of instantiating a template with a variable.  To fix the code to create a two-dimensional vector:

```
typedef std::pair< double,double > A;
typedef std::vector< A > B;
std::vector< B > C;
```

Which creates a variable `C` of type `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<double,double>>>`.

If you're *certain* the vectors inside `C` have sufficient `size()` for `i` and `j` to be valid indices, then you can access the individual `doubles` using:

```
C[i][j].first;
C[i][j].second;
```

Otherwise, you can attempt to access indices `i`, `j` and have the compiler throw an exception if either the outer or inner vector is too small:

```
try
{
    std::cout << C.at(i).at(j).first << ' ' << C.at(i).at(j).second << '\n';
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "caught an exception " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`C.at(i)` is the *i*th B item's reference in C.

`C.at(i).at(j)` is the *j*th A item's reference in *i*th B item's reference in C.

You should refer to `std::vector`'s use specification.